# Program never finishes when I use await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm using DataFlow library in .NET 4.7.1 For some reason, my program never terminates when I have `await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());` within `async` lambda of `ActionBlock`constructor. It would just output stream of lines of`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()` and randomly stop, never reaching `Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed:" + watch.Elapsed);`, though in some cases I have observed that console outputs `"Finished Reading the file"`.

```
 class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfLines = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Number of cores used:" + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((Environment.ProcessorCount * 0.75) * 2.0)));

            BufferBlock<string> queBuffer = new BufferBlock<string>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 100000 });


            var processingBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(async inputline =>
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfLines);
                //Line that causes issue
                //await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString());
            }
            , new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 48,
                SingleProducerConstrained = true,
                BoundedCapacity = 500
            });

            queBuffer.LinkTo(processingBlock);
            //Start
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine("Processing started at:" + DateTime.Now);

            if (File.Exists(args[0]))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0]))
                {
                    string line;
                    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.
                    while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                    {
                        await queBuffer.SendAsync(line);
                    }
                }
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Finished Reading the file");
            }
            queBuffer.Complete();
            processingBlock.Complete();
            await Task.WhenAll(queBuffer.Completion, processingBlock.Completion);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed:" + watch.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of lines read:" + numberOfLines.ToString());           
        }
    }
```

However, if I take out line that causes the issue, it works and reads all the lines from the text file.
`W:\test>.\CompressAMS.exe token2-small.txt
Number of cores used:24
Processing started at:12/17/2018 6:32:50 PM
Finished Reading the file
Time elapsed:00:00:00.3569824
Number of lines read:100000`

Comment: Try calling `Flush()` on `Console.Out`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You mean calling `Flush()` on the line that causes the issue ? Or somewhere else ?

Comment: I don't think you need to await the completion of both tasks. Have you tried just waiting on the final block in the pipeline? Instead of `Task.WhenAll` just do `await processingBlock.Completion;`.

Comment: @pmcilreavy You are right ! I just checked the documentation. It does make sense intuitively as well. Thank you !

Comment: It is [not as async](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,8ca1636fb9d6531f) as you might assume.  So just don't use it and you'll have one less synchronization problem to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do have is a race condition when you complete. Your're calling `Complete()` on both blocks forcing the processing block to stop receiving messages and at that point the buffer may still have data to pass. Then when you await both blocks to complete, if the buffer hasn't sent all of it's messages it will never complete and execution will hang at `Finished Reading File`.

You can safely await both blocks but only call `Complete()` on the buffer and allow TDF to propagate the completion to your downstream processing block:

```
queBuffer.LinkTo(processingBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
/******/
queBuffer.Complete();
await Task.WhenAll(queBuffer.Completion, processingBlock.Completion);
```